# How can I get these two filtering methods to work concurrently?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, filter

I'm working on a search function for a list of people. I have currently have two methods that can filter the list (which is a table of data) - one method is a search filter, the other is a drop down menu of available choices. You can see this here:
http://cambridgefellows.com/directory-of-fellows/

The search function uses this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('input[name=searchFilterInput]').keyup(function() { 
                var searchFilterVal = $('input[name=searchFilterInput]').val();
        searchFilterVal = searchFilterVal.replace(/ /g, '-');
        searchFilterVal = searchFilterVal.toLowerCase();

        if(searchFilterVal == '') {
            $('tr.hide').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
        } else {

            $('tr.fellows').each(function() {
            var pattern = $(this).attr('class');    // the pattern to be matched 
            var match = pattern.match(searchFilterVal);//If pattern matches it returns the match

            if(!match) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hide');

                } else {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
                }
            });
        }
   });
});
```

And the drop down filter uses this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#filter a').click(function() {
        $(this).css('outline','none');
        $('ul#filter.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        //var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

        var filterVal = $(this).text();
        filterVal = filterVal.replace(/ /g, '-');
        filterVal = filterVal.toLowerCase();

        if(filterVal == 'all') {
            $('tr.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('tr.hide').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
                        $('#searchFilterID').val('');
        } else {

            $('tr.fellows').each(function() {
                if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

My question is: How can I get these to function together? I'm not understanding right now why they don't. I need to be able to filter the list with one filter, then additionally filter it by a second filter. For example I might want to use the drop down menu to select only "Center for Public Leadership Emirates Leadership Initiative Fellow" fellowships, and then further refine my search by typing in the word "conf" to narrow the long list down to only Tarig Hilal, who has the word "Conflict" in Focus Areas. However right now when I begin to narrow down with the search field, the filtering performed by the drop down filter no longer affects the list.

I think I understand why it's not working, but I don't have any ideas for how to rearrange my logic to get them to work together. I'd love some suggestions! Thank you.

Edit: I kind of got this to work by removing the "else" functions from both filters and having the "hide" classes be removed when each filter is initially called. It works, but in a very "blinky" way - it's kind of weird. There must be a better way. I definitely would value any suggestions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul#filter a').click(function() {
    $('tr.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).css('outline','none');
    $('ul#filter.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');

    //var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

    var filterVal = $(this).text();
    filterVal = filterVal.replace(/ /g, '-');
    filterVal = filterVal.toLowerCase();

    if(filterVal == 'all') {
        $('tr.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('tr.hide').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
                    $('#searchFilterID').val('');
    } else {

        $('tr.fellows').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
            } else {
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
});
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('input[name=searchFilterInput]').keyup(function() { 
    var searchFilterVal = $('input[name=searchFilterInput]').val();
    searchFilterVal = searchFilterVal.replace(/ /g, '-');
    searchFilterVal = searchFilterVal.toLowerCase();
    $('tr.hide').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');

    if(searchFilterVal == '') {
        $('tr.hide').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
    } else {

        $('tr.fellows').each(function() {
        var pattern = $(this).attr('class');    // the pattern to be matched 
        var match = pattern.match(searchFilterVal);//If pattern matches it returns the match

        if(!match) {
                $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hide');

            } else {
            }
        });
    }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have one of the filter methods call the other filter, providing necessary parameters.

Comment: That sounds promising - but I'm not sure how I would do that. I did get it to work just now by removing the `else` from each filter. But then the user has to reset after each search. But it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: What you mentioned is already working , I've checked  , do check it again.

Comment: I edited my original question to include what I did that did manage to get the filters to work together - but because I am clearing the filter on every keyup there is some flashing and a slight delay if you type many characters into the search field. That makes me wonder if there isn't a more elegant solution than what I've put together so far. But I'll mark the question as answered, since it is at least working.